# Import installed package pyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have pyCharm and Python 3.7. When I go to project `interpreter > packages` and try to download tensorflow, it outputs an error that tells me to do the command `pip install tensorflow`. I did that. Now, how do I import to pyCharm? [This is the error, but I already did pip update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWFaH.png)

Comment: maybe your `Lib` folder (where your packages get installed) is not the same Lib folder as the one you gave PyCharm a path for (PyCharms's Python SDK)

Comment: Please provide output error log.

Comment: How do I check this Lib thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow is not availble for 3.7 version as of now.

Downgrade the python version to 3.6.4

Comment: This is the one! Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm:

Option 1: If you have installed TensorFlow without GPU support, you don’t need to do anything. Simply import TensorFlow to your script and you’re done.

Option 2: If you have installed TensorFlow with GPU support, then you would have also installed CUDA Toolkit 9.0 and cuDNN v7.0 (24.05.2018). You can add the appropriate directories to your %PATH% environment variable. However, even when doing so, PyCharm was complaining! Therefore, it’s much easier to add these directories directly to your PyCharm project structure.

File > Setting > Project Structure > Add Content Root > Add

· path_to_Cuda\v9.0\bin

· path_to_cuDNN\v7.0\bin

Import TensorFlow to your script and you’re done :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even though I used just tensorflow -no gpu- it still says "no module named tensorflow"